# Zooming a qooxdoo widget

Tags: qooxdoo

I have a qx.Desktop application which is used on mobile devices. Some of the content in my application should be zoomable by pinching. So my question is: Is there a way to zoom a qooxdoo widget like for example a qx.ui.basic.Image bigger and smaller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page zooming is configured through the meta tags of your index.html .

If you want to "zoom" or "pinch" one single widget you can use

http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/apiviewer/#qx.bom.element.Transform

and use the `scale` method.

You can access the DOM element through `getContentElement().getDomElement()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy example:

```
var div = yourLayoutElement.getContentElement().getDomElement();
if (div !== undefined && div !== null)
{
   div.style.zoom = scale;
}
```

a scale of 1.0 is 100%